# separating unique error from the rest

Tags: php, sql, pdo, unique

I have a table that one of its columns is `unique`. So when I insert a new row, If the content of that column be duplicate, It gives me an error in `catch(PDOException $e)`. It should be noted that I get any other error also in `catch()`. Now I need to separate `unique` error from other errors. I need to something like this:

```
try{
     // inserting
}

catch(PDOException $e){
   if ($e == 'unique error') {echo 'that is a unique error';}
   else { echo 'that is different error'}
}
```

So I need to a condition like this: `if ($e == 'unique error'){}`. there is any condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions are objects which contain information. The message of the error type should be attached to that object, so you should just be able to:

```
try {

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The exception message should be defined when the exception is thrown.
If you need to separate you could do it by code:

```
try {

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    if($e->getCode() == $someVal) {

    } else if($e->getCode() == $someVal) {

    }
}
```

It'd be best to find out what the error code is in those situations and then compare getCode()

It should be noted that for detecting `unique` error, you should use of this condition:

```
if ((int) $e->getCode() === 23000) { echo 'unique error' }
```

Comment: then separating is impossible ?

Comment: No you could separate by checking the message or by comparing the error code. I added an example with the error code.

Comment: Suggestion: `switch` would read well here; `switch ($e->getCode()) { ... }`

Comment: @DanLugg what is `(int)` ?

Comment: getCode() is actually int|mixed. So typecasting to int would mess with the error code.

Comment: @Sajad Type casting. Probably unnecessary. @RobertCathey `getCode()` is? Dammit PHP.

Comment: So typecasting to int would mess with the error code.

Comment: @RobertCathey TBH, if something is returning a non-int from `getCode()`, I probably don't want to use it. But that's just me ;-)

Comment: The error codes look like '2s534' random. It is a little weird, they should have a better way of comparing certain errors.